# Solve system of equation with arbitrary variable

Tags: equation-solving

Suppose i  have list equations like below
{x(a-1)==0,x y (a-1)==0,x^2(a-1)==0}
Which x and y are arbitrary variable with arbitrary power change every time and unknown variable is a .
I use reduce but it solve equations  for one conditional expression which is below
x==0 & y==0 & a=1 
How can solve problem in general?

Answer (score 2):

```
SolveAlways[{x (a - 1) == 0, x y (a - 1) == 0, x^2 (a - 1) == 0}, {x, y}]
(* {{a -> 1}} *)
```